# Unit Test derived Controller class using protected mediator in base controller in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I am facing issue in mocking mediator that is defined in base class controller as protected property.

I would like to test method of derived class controller, which is using base class property.

Find code details for reference:

```
[ApiController]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    private IMediator _mediator;
    private IUrlHelper _urlHelper;

    protected virtual IMediator Mediator => _mediator ?? (_mediator = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMediator>());
    public BaseController()
    {

    }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class ArchiveFileController : BaseController
{
    public ArchiveFileController()
    {
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody]UploadArchiveCommand model)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await Mediator.Send(new UploadArchiveCommand(model));
            return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = response.Id }, response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }

 }
```

UnitTest :

```
     [Fact]
    public async Task PostArchiveFileTest_Returns_CreatedArchiveFileInformation()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockUploadArchiveCommand = fixture.Create<UploadArchiveCommand>();

        //Action
        _mediatorMock.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<UploadArchiveCommand>(), new CancellationToken())).
         ReturnsAsync(new UploadArchiveViewModel { Identifier = mockUploadArchiveCommand.Identifier, FileName = mockUploadArchiveCommand.FileName });

        var _archiveFileController = new ArchiveFileController();

        var result = await _archiveFileController.Post(mockUploadArchiveCommand);

        var archiveFileInfo = ((CreatedAtActionResult)result).Value as UploadArchiveViewModel;

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(archiveFileInfo.Identifier, mockUploadArchiveCommand.Identifier);
    }
```

[image]

Here Mediator is coming as Null.

Comment: Did you configured `HttpContext`? Why not pass mediator as a parameter to the base class constructor?

Comment: Can we not achieve in this manner?

Comment: @ChandanSingh hi did you changed it to constructor injection  or you found other way around

Comment: I used constructor injection.

Comment: How did you resolve this, I have a similar setup but the Mediator object is injected via Constructor and still getting NullReference Exception for the mediator object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

- Don't create a base class just for common dependencies. A base class here does not add any value.
- Use dependency injection, not service location, for dependencies.

Remove the base class, and just inject the dependencies in your controller class through its constructor. Then you'll be able to mock those dependencies in your unit test.

Comment: is there a way we can test with the same base class implementation